# GCC vs CLANG pointer to char* optimization

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, clang

I have this code:
    mainP.c:

```
int main(int c, char **v){
        char *s = v[0];
        while (*s++ != 0) {
                if ((*s == 'a') && (*s != 'b')) {
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

which I compile with clang and gcc generating the assembly code to compare the optimizations:

```
clang-3.9 -S -masm=intel -O3 mainP.c
gcc -S -masm=intel -O3 mainP.c
```

The compiler version are:

```
clang version 3.9.1-9 (tags/RELEASE_391/rc2)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516
```

The 2 resulting assembly codes are:

gcc assembly code:

```
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        jmp     .L2
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rax], 97
        je      .L5
.L2:
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     BYTE PTR -1[rax], 0
        jne     .L4
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.L5:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

clang assembly code:

```
main:                                   # @main
        .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsi]
        mov     dl, byte ptr [rcx]
        inc     rcx
        .p2align        4, 0x90
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        xor     eax, eax
        test    dl, dl
        je      .LBB0_3
# BB#2:                                 #   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
        movzx   edx, byte ptr [rcx]
        inc     rcx
        mov     eax, 1
        cmp     dl, 97
        jne     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_3:
        ret
```

I notice this: in the gcc assembly code, *s is accessed twice in the loop while *s is accessed only once the clang assembly code.

is there an explanation for the difference?

Then after changing the C code a bit (adding a local char variable), I get about same the assembly code with GCC:

```
int main(int c, char **v){
        char *s = v[0];
        char ch;
        ch = *s;
        while (ch != 0) {
                if ((ch == 'a') && (ch != 'b')) {
                        return 1;
                }
                ch = *s++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Resulting assembly code with GCC:

```
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rax]
        test    dl, dl
        je      .L6
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     dl, 97
        jne     .L5
        jmp     .L8
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        cmp     dl, 97
        je      .L8
.L5:
        add     rax, 1
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR -1[rax]
        test    dl, dl
        jne     .L4
.L6:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.L8:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

Comment: The `s++` is occurring at a different point in the two C++ code fragments.

Comment: clang simply got to omit the second read. Whenever this is good or not, one should do a more careful analysis of the code. Are you asking who is performing better or a more metaphysical *why*?

Comment: I'm not asking which is better. It depends on the situation, if the memory changes between the two reads in the gcc code, the behavior will be different compare to running the clang code.

Comment: in the first c code, I changed char *s to int_fast8_t *s and gcc produces the same assembly code.

Comment: The second read is `*s++`, the difficulty is that it is not always a second read (first iteration). The compiler needs to turn *(c?a:b) into c?*a:*b and notice that *b is redundant when that branch is taken, which gcc misses in this case. Feel free to report this missed optimization to gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: Link to bug report on GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82187

Comment: @Remy: compilers are allowed to assume the memory doesn't change between reads because it's not an `_Atomic char *` or `volatile char *`.  Data races on non-atomic types are Undefined Behaviour in the C standard, which allows the compiler to CSE the loads after transforming the loop.  On Intel Haswell and later, gcc's code can run at about 1 cycle per iteration for long strings.  (Both cmp/jcc macro-fuse into single micro-fused load+compare&branch uops, and Haswell can run execute two branches per clock if at least one is not taken.)  Clang's will bottleneck on the front-end at about 1.5c/iter

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the difference:  compiler optimizations are *hard* to do, and different compilers will optimize your code in different ways.

Because the expression is relatively simple, we can assume that `*s` is the same value in both places and only one load is really needed.

But figuring out that optimization is tricky, because the compiler has to absolutely "know" that "whatever s points to" can't be changed between the first reference and the second.

In your example, clang is better at figuring that out than gcc is.

Comment: is there an option for gcc so that it would produce an assembly code from the first c code with only one access like clang?Also the generated assembly code certainly changes when compiled with different compiler versions.

Comment: I don't know if there is a compiler option, and I'm not surprised there are differences between versions -- each release almost always has improvements/changes to the optimizer.

Comment: If you want to force one access, I recommend using the intermediate variable in your C code, like you did in your second example.

Comment: It's not that gcc thinks doesn't realize it's the same location and it can assume it's unmodified, it's that it doesn't pipeline/transform the loop to special-case a zero-length string and then be able to reuse the loaded character for the `!=0` in the next iteration of the source loop.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129083/gcc-vs-clang-pointer-to-char-optimization#comment79230549_46129083.  gcc/clang also don't auto-vectorize (with SSE2) search loops like this where the iteration count can't be determined before the first iteration, so I think the conditional `return` is problematic.

Comment: Actually it's not the conditional return that's a problem.  Counting matches over the whole string avoids that, but it's still an unknown iteration count, and gcc still loads twice https://godbolt.org/g/vnshJL.